# Watchman Installation - Setting PATH on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, path, watchman

As a react-native novice (I started reading about it yesterday), I started installing all I need according to react-native Get Started guide.

I installed Watchman and according to react-native, it should be added to your PATH.  I am on Macbook Pro and if I type on terminal echo $PATH, I do not see watchman in there.

However, if I type `watchman -v`, it shows me watchman version 4.7.0

So, the npm installer seem to have installed and set watchman properly but it is not in PATH.  Where is it then?  How does terminal recognizes it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've installed watchman on the right place, according to react-native site:
"Watchman - version 3.2 or above. It must be in /usr/local/bin/ or in your $PATH environment variable."